# Use .babelrc from different path

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there a way to provide the path to the .babelrc file to babel-cli?
Something like:

```
babel src --out-dir lib --config random-folder/sub-folder/.babelrc
```

Comment: You could use the [`extends` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/).

Comment: @str I tried but it didn't work: babel src --out-dir lib --extends random-folder/sub-folder/.babelrc

Comment: Can you start a level up and explain why you want the config in a subfolder? It's not a workflow we usually recommend.

Comment: I have a project that is split in 5 modules. I want to avoid having configuration files like .babelrc duplicated in all 5 modules. I want to have a 6th configuration module, that the other 5 will install as a dependency so the actual path would be: ./node_modules/my-conf-module/.babelrc

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Considering the version you are using you may try `extends` or `babelrc`

http://henryzoo.com/babel.github.io/docs/usage/options/

Comment: I'm not able to test this at the moment but will give you grant you the bounty as the 'babelrc' option seems valid.

Comment: Ok, so I was able to test this more. The `babelrc` option doesn't really work for me as I'm using babel 6.x where that option does something different. I ended up using `extends` but not as an CLI option (it doesn't work if you don't have a .babelrc file) but as a property in the .babelrc file.

Comment: Answers should provide something more than a link, now is dead

Answer (score 2):

You can put the .babelrc file in a shared parent directory of the other 5 modules as the [lookup behavior](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#lookup-behavior) of babel regarding the .babelrc is:

> Babel will look for a .babelrc in the current directory of the file
>   being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the
>   directory tree until it finds either a .babelrc, or a package.json
>   with a "babel": {} hash within.

Comment: I know that, but it doesn't work when the modules need to operate on their own as well. This would mean they will only work if they are in a parent project with the .babelrc.