# How to get .babelrc from sub package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

How can I get .babelrc from sub package? I don't want it my main package. I want from node_modules/mySubPackage/node_modules.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use .babelrc from different path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520862/use-babelrc-from-different-path)

Comment: I saw that but there is not good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [babelrcroots](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#babelrcroots),
From the documentation:

> By default, Babel will only search for .babelrc files within the "root" package
>
> .....
>
> This option allows users to provide a list of other packages that should be considered "root" packages when considering whether to load .babelrc files.